# How do I give a name to each slide of a Google Slides Presentation

Tags: google-slides

When doing a presentation, I have a need to jump across slides and looking at the slide number in the presenter view does not help.

[image]

In my case, each slide is devoted to a speaker of an online 60 member zoom meeting. At times, when proceeding in order, speakers are not available or have audio issues so we have to proceed ahead and then at a later point come back to the speakers slide.

Since the slide deck is something I have inherited and currently the titles are not sitting in Title Textboxes. Is there a way to designate a textbox on the slide as a "title"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Slides doesn't include a way to automatically convert a shape text into a title shape. I.E this is the contextual menu shown when right clicking over a text shape:

[image: Contextual menu (right clic over a text box)]

You could use Google Apps Script or another programming platform to use the Google Slides API to modify your presentation.

I think that on each slide you should apply a title layout, then take the text of a shape then add it to the title text shape then depending on if you will need to update the slides later or not you could remove the original text shape or "camouflage" the title shape (i.e. use the same font color as the slide background)

References

- [Structure of a presentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/slides/presentations)

Related

- [Google Slide API how to replace text 'Click to Add Text'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40690634/1595451)

---

Answer to [rev 1](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/142059/1)

Use one of the slide layouts having a Tittle box
[image]

On the title box, write the title

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rubén what you have pointed out is correct, but my problem is I have inherited a slide deck of 100+ slides that have the title written in a non-title textbox. Is there a way to make a textbox as a "title" textbox?

Comment: @MoizTankiwala I think that you should use Google Apps Script for further details,  please edit the question or post a new one.

Comment: Rel. [Introducing the Google Slides API](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/introducing-google-slides-api)

Comment: Not sure how the API reference helps my case?

Comment: Finally I manually converted each side and shifted the title in the title box to get the desired outcome. API could have been a solution, but not worth the time for a single deck that needed to get done. Thanks @Ruben